# How to get drools input ArrayList variable

Tags: arraylist, wso2, drools, mvel

I'm new to WSO2 BRS Drools programming. I'm struggling to get an input as an ArrayList. I have defined a global `ArrayList` variable as below:

```
global java.util.ArrayList<Item> mylist;
```

Answer (score 1):

As described in the [Globals section of the Drools manual](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.0.1.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#d0e5633) the following code will set the value of that global:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
WorkingMemory wm = rulebase.newStatefulSession();
wm.setGlobal( "mylist", list );
```